# Terminate the running download async task in android

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-fragments, android-asynctask, tabwidget

I am working on a image downloader , which is a async downloader. I call it whenever need to display the image on the internet

**Image async downloader (Input are the target imageview, image url)**

```
public class ImageLoader extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {

    private static String TAG = "ImageLoader";
    public InputStream input;
    public ImageView view;
    public String imageURL;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
        try {

            view = (ImageView) params[0];
            imageURL = (String) params[1];

            URL url = new URL(imageURL);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (result != null && view != null) {
            view.setImageBitmap(result);
            view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            view.getBackground().setAlpha(255);
        }
    }
}
```

And the structure of my app is a tabhost , when I switch to a particular tab e.g. at the section 4 , there is a gridview and it will trigger the imageloader asynctask

**The fragment:**

```
gridView.setAdapter(new GalleryAdapter(getActivity() , images));
```

**The adapter:**

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    public ArrayList<GalleryImage> images;

    // Constructor
    public GalleryAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<GalleryImage> _images) {
        mContext = c;
        images = _images;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return images.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if( convertView == null ){
            convertView = (ImageView)new ImageView(mContext);
            int size = (int)(Utility.getScreenWidth(mContext) / 3) - 1; 
            AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(size, size);
            convertView.setLayoutParams(params);
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.darker_gray);
            convertView.getBackground().setAlpha(204); // = 0.8 alpha
        }

        new ImageLoader().execute(convertView,images.get(position).thumbUrl);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I would like to know are there any way to cancel the downloading task when I change the tab? (Since the user leave the tab before all the download is finish , so it is unnecessary to download anymore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking [cancel(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29). Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to [isCancelled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#isCancelled%28%29) to return true. After invoking this method, [onCancelled(Object)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onCancelled%28Result%29), instead of [onPostExecute(Object)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) will be invoked after [doInBackground(Object[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29) returns. **To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of `isCancelled()` periodically from `doInBackground(Object[])`, if possible (inside a loop for instance.)**

In your case, there is no loop in your `doInBackground()` code. In fact it would be better if you turn it into a loop by reading the response stream buffered. This would be more performant and enable you to call `isCancelled()` in the loop.

**Example**: Use [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) to read bytes in chunks and check `isCancelled()` periodically in the loop.

```
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
            try {

                URL url = new URL(imageURL);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                input = connection.getInputStream();

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] byteChunk = new byte[4096];
                int n;

                while ( (n = input.read(byteChunk)) > 0 ) {
                     if(isCancelled()) {
                        return null;
                     }
                     baos.write(byteChunk, 0, n);
                }

                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(baos.toByteArray(), 0, baos.size());

                return myBitmap;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (input != null)
                        input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

   }
```

Of course you should keep a reference to your AsyncTask object to be able to call cancel method on it.

```
    private ImageLoader loader;
    ...
    ...
    loader = new ImageLoader();
    loader.execute();
    ...
    ...
    loader.cancel()
```

Comment: Would you mind provide some code example in more detail? Thanks a lot